# Проблемы при переходе на экран

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, kotlin

При попытке нажать на элемент, который должен переносить меня в фрагмент, выбивает ошибку + вылетает само приложение:

> 02-27 12:01:14.470 21264-21264/com.sai.android E/ACRA: ACRA caught a IllegalArgumentException for com...android
>                                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
>                                                                  at com.sai.android.views.LanguageSelectorFragment.onCreateView(LanguageSelectorFragment.kt)
>                                                                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2069)
>                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:899)
>                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1072)
>                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:852)
>                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
>                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
>                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
>                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

Так понимаю проблемы с back stack'ом. Но в чем именно, локализовать проблему затрудняюсь.

Comment: ну вообще тут вроде написано, что заявленная в Kotlin защита  null safety  собственно обнаружила, что для `savedInstanceState`  значение null, когда быть этого не должно.

Comment: @pavlofff почему так? когда у меня для данног опараметра стоит false? в методе onCreateView

Comment: Я не знаю, из-за не отключаемой null safety я не использую Kotlin, хотя в остальном он мне нравится.

Comment: @pavlofff, обьявляйте везде типы как `nullable` и будет как в Java :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во-первых, как я понял Вы пишете на kotlin, так как логи явно на это указывают.

Ну а во-вторых, при объявлении параметра `savedInstanceState` нужно явно указывать тип - `Bundle?`, это что то вроде баги в Kotlin'e.
Также если будете использовать его в методе `onCreate`, то лучше стоит будет делать следующим образом(в примере использую elvis оператор), а именно присваивать пустой Bundle:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState ?: Bundle())
```

Comment: Никаких танцев с `savedInstanceState ?: Bundle()` не нужно, просто передается `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. И это никакой не баг, просто надо понимать, когда `nullable`, а когда `non-nullable` обьявлять.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в объявлении метода `LanguageSelectorFragment.onCreateView()`, судя по [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)), два из трех параметров могут быть `null`, поэтому на `Kotlin` он должен выглядеть так:

```
fun onCreateView (inflater: LayoutInflater, 
            container: ViewGroup?, 
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
```